# Vector subspace of two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ f, g: V \to W . $ Proof, that the set of vectors from *V* where linear transformation *f* and *g* are equal, forms a vector subspace.

Well, ***f*** and ***g*** are equal if both of those linear transormations are equal to zero, so that set is in kernel which is the subspace itself by definition.

Linear transformations must satisfy: $ f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ and $f(ru) = rf(u) $

where ***u,v*** are vectors from ***V*** and ***r*** is scalar.

Vector subspace satisfies: $ {u}\in V, v\in V $,  then  $  {{(u + v)}\in} V$
                           and for $ r\in R$,  $ ru \in V $

Not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Are you asking why $\ker(f-g)$ is a subspace of $V$ ? If so, the answer is yes : the kernel of *any* linear map $\varphi:X\to Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the linear transformation $f-g$. The vectors $v\in V$ map to the same $w\in W$ for both $f$ and $g$ iff $(f-g)(v)=0$. Thus, the set of vectors you want to show is a subspace is in fact the kernel of $f-g$, hence a subspace.